# What is Bus capacitance in I2C? How it limits number of devices can be connected to the bus?

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, capacitance

Bus capacitance limits number of devices that can be connected by I2C. What problem is encountered if one tries to exceed this limit can anyone explain this in detail please.

Thank you

Comment: With the pullup R, it forms an RC time constant which affects the signal pulses.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/202628/how-is-the-electrical-bus-capacitance-for-i2c-trace-calculated?r=SearchResults&s=4|87.5981

Comment: Is this homework or a college/university assignment?

Comment: @TonyM No its not a homework.I was curious to know and i didnt find any answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is the electrical bus capacitance for I2C trace calculated?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/202628/how-is-the-electrical-bus-capacitance-for-i2c-trace-calculated)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take the tour so you understand how it is used. You didn't find any answers? I Googled "bus capacitance limits I2C" and straightaway got dozens, plenty that explained it. Including https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/202628/how-is-the-electrical-bus-capacitance-for-i2c-trace-calculated on this site. It would appear that it was easier to type in a quick question and let others do the work than to Google. That's not how the site operates, nor how engineering works. Please ask questions as your last resort, not your first. Voting to close for that reason.

Comment: I think some of you are too quick to say this is a duplicate question, but the questions you link are only tangentially related. Understanding how to calculate the trace capacitance of the bus (as is answered in the links) does not answer this question of what it is and why it matters. Everything on stack exchange can be found by googling. Telling someone to look it up themselves is not productive, and implies this site is entirely pointless.

Comment: @KurtE.Clothier, hardly. The point of the site is to encourage learning, not just to provide answers. The former develops better engineers, the latter can do the opposite. This question requires information retrieval, not analysis of a problem, and it is very commonly available information. As I posted, "please ask questions as your last resort, not your first". OPs should stretch their brain first. Otherwise the site can descend into just a point-earner for answering oft-repeated questions.

Comment: The worst possible thing that can happen to this site is to become a collection of "experts" that attack people for asking "bad" questions, as has become of Stack Overflow. Learning requires a thoughtful presentation of information, and telling people to "go look it up" often leads to misunderstandings and awful engineers. I could not care less about points. My goal is to teach. If that means consolidating and repeating information, then so be it.

Comment: @Kurt, that's so far from the circumstances I described and instead sounds like your own crusade, from your comments. (Please address your replies to a user to that user.) I'll leave it there and wish you well, this is far off any useful point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is bus capacitance in I2C?

It's the same as any capacitance - consider the copper traces running over a ground plane. There is some capacitance between the metal, determined by the total area of the traces and dialectic constant between them. Devices on the bus will also have some known capacitance between their IO pins and ground. I2C bus signals can be in the range of 100kbit/s, 400kbit/s or even 1Mbit/s. Adding a capacitor to ground on these signal lines will increase the rise and fall times of the I2C signal lines.

> How does it limit the number of devices on the bus?

Each additional devices adds input capacitance to the signal lines in addition to increasing the bus trace area on the pcb. There's also additional noise added due to the longer traces. As the capacitance on the outputs increases, the signal lines become more sloped. If it's too high, they won't ever reach the threshold for any slave devices on the bus to recognize the signal at all. Or, in the case of the data line, the value might not reach the threshold in time to be registered.

### Electrical Theory

Consider what an I2C connection looks like in a device. The SDA and SCL lines are said to be "Open Drain" which means they are connected to ground through an N channel FET and can sink current. Therefore, they can pull the lines low, but not set them high. That's why you need to connect external pullup resistors to the control lines. The lines are monitored through a diode which has some input threshold which must be overcome.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV2FdM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So pulling the signal low is very quick, but to go high, current must flow through the external resistor and the internal circuitry to ground. This is not instantaneous, and any additional capacitance on the lines will further increase the rise time.

Here are some example waveforms of a 50kHz clock line. The actual capacitor values are just to prove the point.

[image: sck clock waveform]

### Practical Considerations

The device input capacitance is typically around 10pF, but exact values can be found in the datasheet. Another value to consider is the maximum sink current of any of the open drain connections, as this will put a lower limit on the pullup resistor values.

This [technical article from All About Circuits](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/i2c-design-mathematics-capacitance-and-resistance/) does an excellent job at visualizing these concepts and digging deeper into the calculations for signal rise time and acceptable pullup values.

Comment: Thank you for making me understand it @Kurt E. Clothier

Answer (score 0):

You need at least 2 time constants of risetime, given the passive pullup. Otherwise the positive-going waveform will not reach a clean "high" and the data-sampling circuits will conclude a "0" was transmitted.

Thus for 1Kohm pullup and 500 pF total capacitane (wiring, PCB, the ICs hanging on the buss with ESD protection and their data-sampling circuits), you have 500 nanoseconds time constant, and since you need at least 2 tau settling (with that being quite marginal), the bittime must be at least as long as 2 * 500nS = 1,000nS = 1uS => 1MHz rate.

I imagine Philipps has conservative specs on their IP. Respect that.

Comment: Many i2c devices have maximum sink current specifications of 2-3 mA so 1kohm would be too low in a 5v system. The lowest acceptable would be 2.2k.

Comment: The NXP spec only requires 3mA of sink current in standard mode and fast mode, @KevinWhite makes a valid point. The specified maximum bus load for these two modes is not 500pF, it is 400pF.